# Where to save uploaded files in server?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, web-hosting

We have developed a web application using JSP and Servlet. The server we use is Tomcat 7. We have hired a host (Daily Razor) with "private JVM" to launch the application in production level.

Now, in our application, user can visit a particular form, browse for a file in his PC and upload it to the server. But I have a question there; what is the best place to store these files? Mainly there are 3 types of files so we would like to categorize them into, "Office', "Home" and "Other" and create 3 folders for them. But inside which main folder these 3 folders should be made?

The main important this is that these files should not be accessed via a URL (because then anyone can get them ), but a Servlet can. Apart from that, the location (String) should be saved in our MySQL database so the file can be accessed again without an issue.

We have developed the application using Netbeans IDE so the folder structure is like below.

[image]

I look forward for your answers.

Comment: You can't save the files anywhere in that folder structure; Web app directories should be assumed to be read-only. Pass a property with a path to your program.

Comment: @chrylis: OK, That is confusing. Can you explain more please? I haven't done this before.

Comment: Uploaded files are data. Data are stored somewhere on the file system of the server, or in the database with the rest of the submitted data. Not inside the application structure.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yeah, fine, but where? You mean just create a folder in server and save it?

Comment: @JBNizet: Can we create something like this/ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592685/how-to-create-a-folder-in-tomcat-webserver-using-java-program

Comment: Yes, pretty much. If you expect many files to be uploaded, you should think about saving them in several different folders, because some file system/operations are very slow if thousands of files are stored in the same folder.

Comment: @JBNizet: However the "File Path" make no sense to me. I know it is the path to the file, but it is not like mentioning the path as "C:/Program files/.....". How to make a "correct" path?

Comment: If your server uses Windows, the path of the folder where to store files would indeed look like `c:/uploaded/office` of `c:/uploaded/other`. If your server uses Linux, it would look like `/var/uploaded/office` or `/var/uploaded/other`. It's of course up to you to create these directories on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use a java property to specify the directory where the files should be stored, and pass it on to tomcat during start up.
Also, it might be a good idea to separate the files per user.

**Possible Solution:**

```
-Duser.data.export.dir=D:\users_export\directory
```

In your java code, read the property

```
String property = System.getProperty("user.data.export.dir");
```

Now lets say for user 'A'

```
String userName = getCurrentUser();
Path userDirHome = Paths.get(property, userName, "Home");<br/>
```

Now use userDirHome to store the data.

**Suggestion:** When you store the file location in the DB, ensure that you do not store the complete path, only store the relative path, like "Home/myFile.txt".

This will help you at a later point in time when, there is any change in the directory where the file are stored.

Comment: Yeah, separating the files per user is definitely possible, it is just to avoid naming conflicts. If you do not wish to separate the files per user, then you will need to generate unique file names and have some kind of mapping to those files based on the user

Comment: However the "File Path" make no sense to me. I know it is the path to the file, but it is not like mentioning the path as "C:/Program files/.....". How to make a "correct" path?