# Creating a storage for images directly in tomcat folder (Java)

Tags: java, html, tomcat, containers, storage

I searched around the web and here and couldn't find a conclusive answer to this rather simple question. I am using Java+MySQL+HTML and CSS.

I created a webapp, and in this webapp the user can upload the photos path to the database .At the same time I am creating a folder completely outside of tomcat to copy inserted images there. The folder is on my desktop as I am on localhost, but I want to make the storage on the server not on my desktop.

After checking stackoverflow I saw that it is bad to store photos/images in tomcats webapp/AppName folder because this will overwrite the images all the time at redeployment which I don't want to do.

My tomcat folder is on desktop. Can I create a folder to store the images for this specific app here:

\Desktop\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.24\   ?

The folder would be called TripAppImages like \Desktop\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.24\TripAppImages and will be besides all of tomcats other folders like bin, conf, etc. I will also use this folder to display the images that the user inserted , back to him in a html page.

**EDIT:** ok so I have finally come upon a message from here [how to create a folder in tomcat webserver using java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592685/how-to-create-a-folder-in-tomcat-webserver-using-java-program) from BalusC which says:

> "Please note that you shouldn't store the files in the expanded WAR folder, or they will get lost every time you redeploy the webapp. Store them on a fixed path outside Tomcat's /webapps folder."

This I believe means that I can store the images like this \Desktop\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.24\TripAppImages. As long ass they are not in the webapp folder it means they won't be overwritten.

Comment: The tomcat folders you should avoid are `temp`, `webapps`, `work`, and your app folder that is inside webapp and work, because those can be erased/replaced with deploys or cleanings. But the only thing keeping you from creating a folder like `\Desktop\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.24\chocolate\strawberry\icecream\` and putting all images there is just organization, patterns and your company/I.T. policies.

Comment: cool, i guess this is what i needed, thanks ! If u write it as an answer i will give you rep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only folders you should avoid are `temp`, `webapp`, `work` and its subfolders, because yes, those folders can have its content replaced or deleted during deploys and cleanings, every other folder inside tomcat can be considered as 'just a folder' that, if you don't modify its contents, you can use the way you want. Of course it would not be normal or standard to, for example, store videos inside `Tomcat\bin` but if you don't touch the original files there you can do it.

So technically speaking, you can create a folder like `\Desktop\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.24\icecream` and put images there it will not be erased or replaced by a deploy.

If it is just for you, temporary or not `production`, just avoid the three folders mentioned at the beginning and you are good to go.